# "... wie auch Norbert Lehmann für den Sport."

Tags: meaning, conjunction

Nachrichtensprecherin [Barbara Hahlweg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Hahlweg) begrüßt die Zuschauer bei den [heute-Nachrichten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heute_(Fernsehsendung)) im ZDF gewöhnlich mit den Worten:

> > "Guten Abend. Schön, dass Sie dabei sind, wie auch Norbert Lehmann für den Sport."

Mir scheint die Formulierung

> > "Schön, dass Sie dabei sind, wie auch Norbert Lehmann für den Sport."

grammatikalisch zweifelhaft, und auf jeden Fall stilistisch schlecht. Zwar ist die Fügung *Hans ist [ebenso] dabei, wie auch Peter [dabei ist].* grammatikalisch korrekt. Mit *wie auch* ist aber gemeint, dass Hans und Peter, wo auch immer sie "dabei" sind, dieselbe Rolle einnehmen. Die Konjunktion *wie auch* drückt Äquivalenz aus. Beide sind auf dieselbe Art und Weise Teilnehmer und könnten, ohne dass es für einen von ihnen einen Unterschied macht, die Plätze wechseln.

Beispiel:

> Wir fahren dieses Jahr alle zusammen an die Nordsee. Hans ist dabei, wie auch Peter.

Das heißt, Hans und Peter fahren mit.

Frau Hahlweg aber stellt zwei Aussagen mit `wie auch` einander gleich, in denen das `dabei sein` unterschiedliche Bedeutung hat. Denn als Zuschauer vor dem Fernseher "dabei" zu sein ist ja nicht dasselbe wie als Moderator vor der Kamera dafür zuständig zu sein, vom Sport zu berichten. Insofern ist der Zuschauer zwar "dabei", aber eben *nicht* wie der Moderator Norbert Lehmann, sondern anders.

Ist meine grammatische Analyse korrekt, oder trügt mich mein Sprachgefühl und Frau Hahlwegs Formulierung ist stilistisch astrein.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Mit den Regeln kenne ich mich nicht so aus, daher nur ein Gefühl: es ist ein Mix. Für den Teil, den Frau Hahlweg moderiert, ist Herr Lehmann genauso Zuschauer wie die vorm Bildschirm. Für den Teil, den Herr Lehmann moderiert, hat er eine andere Funktion als die Zuschauer - begrüßt er die vorm Bildschirm separat oder nicht?

Comment: Stil hat starke subjektive Anteile, weshalb "stilistisch astrein" ein relativ unklarer Begriff ist. Was meinst du damit? Auf welche normative Referenz beziehst du dich?

Comment: Geht es nun um Grammatik oder Stil? An der Grammatik ist nichts auszusetzen. Stil ist Geschmackssache. *Die Kinder waren dabei wie auch der Hund.* Der Hund aber sicher auf ganz andere Art und Weise als die Kinder.

Comment: Könnte sich *wie auch* nicht auf *[es ist] schön* beziehen -- 'es ist schön, dass Sie dabei sind, **wie** es **auch** schön ist, dass Norbert Lehman für den Sport dabei ist'?

Answer (score 3):

Es kann keine Rede davon sein, dass "dabei sein" dieselbe Rolle in derselben Situation bedeutet. Wäre das so, bräuchten wir ja keine erläuternden Ausdrücke wie "für den Sport", "als Berichterstatter" oder "per Teleschaltung".

Im übrigen ist die Rolle von Menschen in Situationen stark von der Perspektive des Sprechers abhängig. Bei einer Trauung haben der Pfarrer, das Brautpaar und der Organist für das Familienstandsregister sehr verschiedene Funktionen. Für das Gesundheitsamt zählt dagegen nur, daß sie alle eine Stunde lang im selben Raum anwesend waren. Die Rolle ist also entweder identisch oder nicht, je nachdem, unter welchem Gesichtspunkt man anfragt.

Comment: Außerdem bezieht sich das "wie auch" meiner Ansicht nach auf das "schön, dass...". Und in dieser Hinsicht sind die beiden Teile tatsächlich äquivalent: "Es ist schön, dass Sie dabei sind, ebenso wie es schön ist, dass Norbert Lehmann für den Sport dabei ist."

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Da stimme ich zu, 'wie ich auch' schon unter der Frage kommentiert habe, ohne diese ältere Anmerkung vorher gesehen zu haben.